# error when run php artisan queue:work on the server

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send emails using queuing jobs 
so when I dispatch job it stores the job in jobs table in the database and to send the email I need to run this command on the server

```
php artisan queue:work
```

but it produces an error:

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in
>   name resolution [tcp://redis:6379]

so what's the issue here

Comment: show the code of `.env` file

Comment: BROADCAST_DRIVER=log 
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_PASSWORD=null

may be the problem because I use the redis in my application , and in the same time the queue driver is database ??

Comment: Write your redis host ip like `REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1` (if local) instead of `REDIS_HOST=redis` inside your `.env` file.

Comment: Hello @EmanSayma If someone gives an answer, at least give a response to comment on it, we are trying to should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change `REDIS_HOST=redis` to `REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1`, it is looking for a host named `redis` and not finding it

After change of *`.env`* must be clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`